# Facebook graph api: get post sharing history

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need this functionality: application must check shared or not user given post on his wall. Now I'm able get posts from user wall, and shared posts have status_type shared_story, but I can't get from which post it was shared, is there any way add this functionality with facebook api?